# MemoryError with python using keras and theano

Tags: python, numpy, keras, theano, theano-cuda

I tried [this](http://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) keras tutorial. I'm using theano on my other project, so I changed keras to use theano and not tenorflow. But when I run this tutorial I get this error first:

> nvcc fatal   : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH

And after some time, in the first Epoch (out of 3), on the sample number 13056 (out of 25000) i get this error:

> File "test_keras.py", line 28, in 
>       model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=3, batch_size=64)
>
> File "C:\Users\domi1_000\Anaconda3\envs\Pyhon27\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 845, in fit
>       initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
>
> File "C:\Users\domi1_000\Anaconda3\envs\Pyhon27\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1485, in fit
>       initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
>
> File "C:\Users\domi1_000\Anaconda3\envs\Pyhon27\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1140, in _fit_loop
>       outs = f(ins_batch)
>
> File "C:\Users\domi1_000\Anaconda3\envs\Pyhon27\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 1094, in **call**
>       return self.function(*inputs)
>
> File "C:\Users\domi1_000\Anaconda3\envs\Pyhon27\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 898, in **call**
>       storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
>
> File "C:\Users\domi1_000\Anaconda3\envs\Pyhon27\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\link.py", line 325, in raise_with_op
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
>
> File "C:\Users\domi1_000\Anaconda3\envs\Pyhon27\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 884, in **call**
>       self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
>
> File "C:\Users\domi1_000\Anaconda3\envs\Pyhon27\lib\site-packages\theano\scan_module\scan_op.py", line 989, in rval
>       r = p(n, [x[0] for x in i], o)
>
> File "C:\Users\domi1_000\Anaconda3\envs\Pyhon27\lib\site-packages\theano\scan_module\scan_op.py", line 978, in p
>       self, node)
>
> File "theano/scan_module/scan_perform.pyx", line 445, in theano.scan_module.scan_perform.perform (C:\Users\domi1_000\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_St
>   epping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.12-64\scan_perform\mod.cpp:5259)
>
> MemoryError:
>
> Apply node that caused the error: forall_inplace,cpu,grad_of_scan_fn}(TensorConstant{500}, Subtensor{int64:int64:int64}.0, Elemwise{tanh}.0, Alloc.0, InplaceDimShuffle{0,2,1}.0, Elemwise{Composite{(i0
>    - sqr(i1))}}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int64}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int64}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int64}.0, Alloc.0, Alloc.0, Alloc.0, TensorConstant{500}, Subtensor{::, int64:int64:}.0, Subtenso
>   r{::, :int64:}.0, Subtensor{::, int64::}.0, Subtensor{::, int64:int64:}.0, InplaceDimShuffle{1,0}.0, InplaceDimShuffle{1,0}.0, InplaceDimShuffle{1,0}.0, Alloc.0, InplaceDimShuffle{1,0}.0)
>
> Toposort index: 148
>   Inputs types: [TensorType(int64, scalar), TensorType(float32, 3D), TensorType(float32, 3D), TensorType(float32, 3D), TensorType(float32, 3D), TensorType(float32, 3D), TensorType(float32, 3D), TensorTy
>   pe(float32, 3D), TensorType(float32, 3D), TensorType(float32, 3D), TensorType(float32, 3D), TensorType(float32, 3D), TensorType(int64, scalar), TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matrix)
>   , TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matr
>   ix)]
>
> Inputs shapes: [(), (500L, 64L, 100L), (500L, 64L, 100L), (500L, 64L, 400L), (500L, 100L, 64L), (500L, 64L, 100L), (500L, 64L, 400L), (500L, 64L, 100L), (500L, 64L, 100L), (501L, 64L, 100L), (501L, 64
>   L, 100L), (2L, 100L, 400L), (), (100L, 100L), (100L, 100L), (100L, 100L), (100L, 100L), (100L, 100L), (100L, 100L), (100L, 100L), (100L, 400L), (100L, 100L)]
>   Inputs strides: [(), (-25600L, 400L, 4L), (25600L, 400L, 4L), (102400L, 1600L, 4L), (-25600L, 4L, 400L), (25600L, 400L, 4L), (-1600L, 800000L, 4L), (-25600L, 400L, 4L), (-25600L, 400L, 4L), (25600L, 4
>   00L, 4L), (25600L, 400L, 4L), (160000L, 1600L, 4L), (), (1600L, 4L), (1600L, 4L), (1600L, 4L), (1600L, 4L), (4L, 1600L), (4L, 1600L), (4L, 1600L), (1600L, 4L), (4L, 1600L)]
>   Inputs values: [array(500L, dtype=int64), 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown', array(500L, dty
>   pe=int64), 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown']
>   Outputs clients: [[], [], [Subtensor{int64}(forall_inplace,cpu,grad_of_scan_fn}.2, Constant{1})], [Subtensor{::int64}(forall_inplace,cpu,grad_of_scan_fn}.3, Constant{-1})]]
>
> HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that do
>   es not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.

This also happened to me on my other project, but there problem was dimension mismatch. It couldn't match node with dimensions 300x200 to node with dimension 100x100.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it says what it says. your GPU reached memory limit . If you are using Theano as backend try setting CNMeM and  cuDNN. how much memory does your GPU have?

Comment: It has 1 GB of memory.

Comment: Dude, there is no chance for it to work. Maybe if you try to downsize batch to 2 or 4 if it is image, but highly unlikely sorry. Here you can have some hours of GPU for free  - try it floydhub.com

Comment: Oh, ok, thank you.
I'm new to this so I don't have the feeling about requirements and size. Anyway, thanks again.